# Access to name of a Model in laravel Blade template

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Model Named `Lesson` like this :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Lesson extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public    $primaryKey = 'lesson_id';
    protected $dates      = ['deleted_at', 'start_date', 'end_date'];

    protected $guarded = [
        'lesson_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'
    ];

    protected $appends = ['start_date_picker', 'end_date_picker'];
}
```

And in `LessonController` show() method, I send an Instance of that model to a view named `lesson-show` as a variable named `$lesson` .

Now I want a property or method to get name of that model in `lesson-show` views so that when called it, return a string like `App\Lesson`, means along with Class namespace.

Is there any method or property to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you want this, but still:

```
dd(get_class($lesson));
```